# Visual Studio Post-Rebuild / Post-NoBuild Event?

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild

I'm working on a project where I need a script to execute when someone hits "F5" or "F6", even if the code in the project hasn't changed.

The script is responsible for copying data from a different directory - data that may have changed.

I've noticed that this works properly as a post-build event, but only if the project is actually rebuilt. How do I get the event to trigger without requiring a clean each time?

Comment: Difficult to answer without more detail but two *possibilities*: (a) Execute your script as a **pre-** build; (b) Add the script as a custom build tool, by including the data file to be copied into the project.

Comment: @AdrianMole I actually did have it as a prebuild script, however if you've made no changes to the code inside the project, the prebuild script is actually never called, because "Build" never happens. 
The context is that I'm building a game engine for a class I'm taking, and we collaborate with artists who may make changes to the art assets, and those assets need to be copied to the output directory when you launch the debugger, regardless of whether new code needs to be compiled.
I figured out a solution though, posted it below if it lends any clarity to what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps I followed to setup the script to run when I needed it:

1. Opened Project > Properties
2. Navigate to Custom Build Step > General
3. Put the script command in the "Command Line" field
4. Set an arbitrary output filename (this is required, if you don't have an output filename, visual studio will skip your custom build step) I chose an arbitrary filename ".filename" if I were to get fancy I'd also have the script output a log to this file
5. Set the "Execute After" field to "FinalizeBuildStatus" This ensures that the command will execute after the build status has been established (which happens in all circumstances when you'd hit F5 or F6, even if you haven't changed any code in the project).

I was surprised not to find these steps clearly outlined elsewhere online. Perhaps I'm bad at googling, but since I solved my own problem I find it only fitting to share in case someone else has this problem.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer:)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I had to wait the obligatory 2 days before doing so, but forgot :)